# default gateway seems to be ignored

Tags: linux, networking

here's my phone's network configuration (note that rndis0 denotes the usb network interface)

```
~ $ ifconfig
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (Permission denied). Limited output.
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)

rmnet_data2: flags=65<UP,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.145.149.154  netmask 255.255.255.252
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)

rndis0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.90.238  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.90.255
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
```

I can ping the IP of the desktop computer connected on the other side of the usb cable

```
~ $ ping 192.168.90.175 # desktop computer's IP
PING 192.168.90.175 (192.168.90.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.90.175: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.486 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.90.175: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
^C
--- 192.168.90.175 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1016ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.486/0.787/1.088/0.301 ms
```

But on phone, I cannot ping the router that my desktop computer is connected to via a standard ethernet port:

```
~ $ ping 192.168.2.1
connect: Network is unreachable
```

This is expected, given the routing table on my phone

```
~ $ su
:/data/data/com.termux/files/home # ../usr/bin/route -n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
100.145.149.152 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 rmnet_data2
192.168.90.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 rndis0
```

But even after I change the routing table on my phone to add a default gateway, I am still unable to reach the router

```
:/data/data/com.termux/files/home # ../usr/bin/route add default gw 192.168.90.175 dev rndis0                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
:/data/data/com.termux/files/home # ../usr/bin/route -n                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.90.175  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 rndis0
100.145.149.152 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 rmnet_data2
192.168.90.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 rndis0
:/data/data/com.termux/files/home # ping 192.168.2.1
connect: Network is unreachable
2|:/data/data/com.termux/files/home # ping -I rndis0 192.168.2.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) from 192.168.90.238 rndis0: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.90.238: icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.90.238: icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

maybe I need to configure something on the computer and I will get to that. But from the error messages, it looks like that there is a problem even on the side of the phone: specifically, the phone seems to be ignoring the default gateway entry in the routing table.  For example when i dont specify the interface in ping, I get "network is unreachable". When I do specify the interface, I get the "destination host unreachable" from the phone's IP and NOT the IP of the default gateway (192.168.90.175:) which is reachable/pingable as the log above shows.

Comment: Can you ping your router?

Comment: `rndis0` is typically the mobile WAN connection and I suppose you want to set a route for your local network.

Comment: rndis0 is the usb network interface between my phone and desktop. I want to be able to send packets from phone to the desktop over this connection

Comment: @AbhishekAnand You are missing something here. I can do the same thing by 1. connecting my android phone via USB 2. enabling usb tethering 3. getting my PCs IP 4. pinging or SSHing into my PC from termux. This should work without adding routes or any configuration and does not require root privileges.

Comment: thanks @mashuptwice. that works even for me if I let the interface on the desktop use DHCP. previously, I was choosing static IPs. But on the phone, I want to get beyond the desktop computer and access the other networks the desktop is connected to. I have updated my question.

Comment: I'm not even sure if you are able to set the network parameters thru classical linux tools on modern android versions, you might want to ask that on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: About accessing other networks than the tethering net: You basically would need to make your computer a router by telling it to forward the packages between your tethering interface and your LAN. I'm not sure if this is possible on windows machines, but you can read up on how to do that on linux [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/453254/routing-between-two-networks-on-linux). I still don't have an idea what your endgoal is, I can assure you that this "solution" that you are constructing here will be in no way convenient or stable to use, regardless of what you are trying to do with it.